# Change Webview height dynamically

Tags: android, webview

i am trying to change the webview height dynamically, this is my code,

```
 WebView answerHtml = new WebView(this);
            answerHtml.setId(i);
            answerHtml.setOnTouchListener(AnswerListener);
            answerHtml.setBackgroundColor(0);
            answerHtml.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ans_back);
            answerHtml.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            answerHtml.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, a.getText(), "text/html",
                    "utf-8", null);
            ansCellLayout.setTag(OPTION_LAYOUT_TAG);
            ansCellLayout.addView(answerHtml);
```

and this is in `for loop` but the height is only this big

---

---

i want it to have more height i have tried setting minimun height,scaling but not working please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code while adding WebView to your layout.

```
ansCellLayout.addView(answerHtml, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100));
```

Hoping that `ansCellLayout` is `LinearLayout` and WebView will be created with 100 width and 100 height.

Comment: ok but what abt this line ansCellLayout.addView(answerHtml); should i remove?

Comment: @Goofy Check my edited answer. You are just adding layout parameters so that it will create the webview in 100 by 100 height.

Comment: hey thanks it works but the webview is not in center ? how to do it?

Comment: and what if the webview textsize increase that means will have 3 lines then the height 100 is not proper how to fix this